# transformer training loss not decreasing - Val. Acc/cy stuck at 0.58

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-fake

I am training a multi-branch pytorch based pipeline for deepfake detection. I am trying to implement the following model as presented in the paper:

*A Transformer-Based DeepFake-Detection Method
for Facial Organs
(Ziyu Xue, et. al,Electronics 2022 ,1 ,4143.https://doi.org/10.3390/
electronics11244143 )*

[Multi-Branch Occlusion-robust Deepfake detector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDWdq.png)

**Model/Architecture**: For the transformer encoders, I have my own custom implementation of MHA as seen below. I have also tried using pretrained ViT on Imagenet1K by torchvision.models, but observe same results. I train on batch sizes of [60,128,256] with the training loss fluctuating in the range [0.5 - 0.9] and not decreasing further.

**Dataset**: I train on the FaceForensics++ dataset, with a full size of 44335 images with a 80/20 split and 1/4 class imbalance. For the transformer I use model/embedding size dk=252.

I have tried altering the lr from [0.1 , 0.0001, 1e-6] even 1e-8 with exponential lr decay scheduler of gam=0.9.
Could you provide any alternatives I could experiment with ?
(the dataset is checked; no nan values. Also the objects detected from the images and used as input to the transformers are checked and of normal quality).

```py
  #main model class
        class VisionTransformer(nn.Module):
            def __init__(
                self,
                embed_dim,
                hidden_dim,
                num_channels,
                num_heads,
                num_layers,
                num_classes,
                patch_size,
                num_patches,
                batch_size,
                device,
                dropout=0.2, #20% prob dropout
            ):
                """
                Inputs:
                    embed_dim - Dimensionality of the input feature vectors to the Transformer
                    hidden_dim - Dimensionality of the hidden layer in the feed-forward networks
                                within the Transformer
                    num_channels - Number of channels of the input (3 for RGB)
                    num_heads - Number of heads to use in the Multi-Head Attention block
                    num_layers - Number of layers to use in the Transformer
                    num_classes - Number of classes to predict
                    patch_size - Number of pixels that the patches have per dimension
                    num_patches - Maximum number of patches an image can have
                    dropout - Amount of dropout to apply in the feed-forward network and
                            on the input encoding
                """
                super().__init__()

                self.patch_size = patch_size
                self.patch_dim = (3,256,256)
                self.organ_dim = (1,3,256,256)
                # Layers/Networks
                self.input_layer = nn.Linear(num_channels * (patch_size**2), embed_dim)    #takes [ , #patches, features] for embedd
                self.embed_dim = embed_dim # size of feature inputs to linear layer - BEFORE batch embeddings
     
                self.device =device
               

                self.input_layers = torch.nn.ModuleDict({
                    'in_mouth' : nn.Linear(1014,embed_dim),
                    'in_right_eyebrow': nn.Linear(1014,embed_dim),
                    'in_left_eyebrow': nn.Linear(1014,embed_dim),
                    'in_right_eye':nn.Linear(1014,embed_dim),
                    'in_left_eye':nn.Linear(1014,embed_dim),
                    'in_nose':nn.Linear(1014,embed_dim),
                    'in_jaw':nn.Linear(1014,embed_dim),
                    'in_face':nn.Linear(1014,embed_dim)

                })


                self.cnn_dict = torch.nn.ModuleDict({
                    'cnn_mouth': CNN_encoder1().to(device) ,
                    'cnn_right_eyebrow': CNN_encoder2().to(device),
                    'cnn_left_eyebrow': CNN_encoder2().to(device),
                    'cnn_right_eye': CNN_encoder2().to(device),
                    'cnn_left_eye': CNN_encoder2().to(device),
                    'cnn_nose': CNN_encoder3().to(device),
                    'cnn_jaw': CNN_encoder2().to(device),
                    'cnn_face': CNN_encoder2().to(device),

                })


                self.transformer_dict = torch.nn.ModuleDict({
                    'tf_mouth':nn.Sequential(
                        *(AttentionBlock(embed_dim, hidden_dim, num_heads, dropout=dropout) for _ in range(num_layers))
                        ),
                    'tf_right_eyebrow':nn.Sequential(
                        *(AttentionBlock(embed_dim, hidden_dim, num_heads, dropout=dropout) for _ in range(num_layers))
                        ),
                    'tf_left_eyebrow':nn.Sequential(
                        *(AttentionBlock(embed_dim, hidden_dim, num_heads, dropout=dropout) for _ in range(num_layers))
                        ),
                    'tf_right_eye':nn.Sequential(
                        *(AttentionBlock(embed_dim, hidden_dim, num_heads, dropout=dropout) for _ in range(num_layers))
                        ),
                    'tf_left_eye':nn.Sequential(
                        *(AttentionBlock(embed_dim, hidden_dim, num_heads, dropout=dropout) for _ in range(num_layers))
                        ),
                    'tf_nose':nn.Sequential(
                        *(AttentionBlock(embed_dim, hidden_dim, num_heads, dropout=dropout) for _ in range(num_layers))
                        ),
                    'tf_jaw':nn.Sequential(
                        *(AttentionBlock(embed_dim, hidden_dim, num_heads, dropout=dropout) for _ in range(num_layers))
                        ),
                    'tf_0':nn.Sequential(
                        *(AttentionBlock(embed_dim, hidden_dim, num_heads, dropout=dropout) for _ in range(num_layers))
                        )

                })



                self.mlp_head_dict =torch.nn.ModuleDict({
                                           'o_mouth': nn.Sequential( nn.LayerNorm(self.embed_dim),

                                            #nn.Linear(8*embed_dim, embed_dim),
                                            nn.Linear(self.embed_dim,1)),    #embded dim=transformer output,
                                            'o_right_eyebrow': nn.Sequential( nn.LayerNorm(self.embed_dim),

                                            #nn.Linear(8*embed_dim, embed_dim),
                                            nn.Linear(self.embed_dim,1)),

                                            'o_left_eyebrow': nn.Sequential( nn.LayerNorm(self.embed_dim),

                                            #nn.Linear(8*embed_dim, embed_dim),
                                            nn.Linear(self.embed_dim,1)),

                                            'o_right_eye': nn.Sequential( nn.LayerNorm(self.embed_dim),

                                            #nn.Linear(8*embed_dim, embed_dim),
                                            nn.Linear(self.embed_dim,1)),
                                            'o_left_eye': nn.Sequential( nn.LayerNorm(self.embed_dim),

                                            #nn.Linear(8*embed_dim, embed_dim),
                                            nn.Linear(self.embed_dim,1)),

                                            'o_nose': nn.Sequential( nn.LayerNorm(self.embed_dim),

                                            #nn.Linear(8*embed_dim, embed_dim),
                                            nn.Linear(self.embed_dim,1)),

                                            'o_jaw': nn.Sequential( nn.LayerNorm(self.embed_dim),

                                            #nn.Linear(8*embed_dim, embed_dim),
                                            nn.Linear(self.embed_dim,1)),

                                            'o_8': nn.Sequential( nn.LayerNorm(self.embed_dim),

                                            #nn.Linear(8*embed_dim, embed_dim),
                                            nn.Linear(self.embed_dim,1)),

                                            })
                                                                                                                      #num_classes = #ouptut neurons
                self.classify_head = nn.Linear(8,2)
                self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

                # Parameters/Embeddings
                self.cls_token = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, 1, embed_dim))                    #b , img_flattened , embed
                self.pos_embedding = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, 1 + num_patches, embed_dim))  #b, numpathces=32 ,embed

                self.num_patches = num_patches
                self.num_organs = 7

 
            def forward(self, z):
                _B = z[0].shape[0]
                (x , paths) = z   #patch size B


                self.vect_gr = torch.empty((_B , 8*self.embed_dim))   #6 = 5 organs + 1 face. init on each forward call 

                """
                1st brach: organ-level transformer
                """
    
                #print("1")
                org_list_dict = {
                    "o_mouth":torch.zeros((0,self.embed_dim)).to(self.device),
                    "o_right_eyebrow":torch.zeros((0,self.embed_dim)).to(self.device),
                    "o_left_eyebrow":torch.zeros((0,self.embed_dim)).to(self.device),
                    "o_right_eye":torch.zeros((0,self.embed_dim)).to(self.device),
                    "o_left_eye":torch.zeros((0,self.embed_dim)).to(self.device),
                    "o_nose":torch.zeros((0,self.embed_dim)).to(self.device),
                    "o_jaw":torch.zeros((0,self.embed_dim)).to(self.device)
                }
               # print("2")


                for j in range(_B):         #iterate over batch images
                    selected_organs = self.organ_selector( paths[j] , organs=True)    #organ selection module -> returns dict of detected organs in all images.

                    if selected_organs != {}:

                        for idx,(name, loc) in enumerate(FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS.items()):      #iter over organs 

                            if name in selected_organs:                                     #iter over orans detected

                                #run entire pipeline from cnn to tf output. Store outputs per organ
                                #for all batches
                                x1 = self.cnn_dict["cnn_"+name](selected_organs[name].to(self.device))

                                #transformer output size

                                x1 = img_to_patch(x1, self.patch_size)          #(1,flattened h*w , c*p_h*p_w)
                                                                                #(40,*)

                                x1 = self.input_layers["in_"+name](x1.to(device))                       #(*,250) *=(1,h*w)

                                B, T ,_ = x1.shape
                                #patch dims

                                cls_token = self.cls_token.repeat(1, 1, 1)  #repeat b times at d=0


                                x1 = torch.cat([x1 , cls_token] , 1)

                                x1 = x1 + self.pos_embedding[:, : T + 1]  #([:,:t+1). keep max T = N patches 

                                x1=self.dropout(x1)

                                x1=x1.transpose(0,1)

                                #transformer input dims

                                x1 = self.transformer_dict["tf_"+name](x1)  #(1,1014)

                                x1=x1[0]

                                #transformer output dims are
                 
                                #cat organ name to existing organ list dict
                                org_list_dict["o_"+name] = torch.cat([org_list_dict["o_"+name], x1] , dim = 0)   #concat with rest organs of batch



                            else:    #no organ of name detected
                                org_list_dict["o_"+name] = torch.cat([ org_list_dict["o_"+name] ,  torch.zeros((1, self.embed_dim)).to(self.device)] , dim = 0)


                    else:
                        #no organs detected,7 expected
                        for name,_ in FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS.items():
                            org_list_dict["o_"+name] = torch.cat([ org_list_dict["o_"+name] ,torch.zeros((1, self.embed_dim)).to(self.device) ])

                """
                2nd brach: face-level transformer
                """
                img = torch.empty((0,3,260,260))
                for j in range(_B):
                    print(x[j].size())
                    x2 = self.organ_selector(x[j] , organs = False)  #whole face
                    x2 = x2.permute(0,3,1,2)
                    img = torch.cat([img, x2] ,)

                x2 = self.cnn_dict["cnn_face"](img.to(self.device))

                x2 = img_to_patch(x2, self.patch_size)


                x2 = self.input_layers["in_face"](x2.to(self.device))
                B, T, _ = x2.shape #(T is number of patches)


                # Add CLS token and positional encoding
                cls_token = self.cls_token.repeat(_B, 1, 1)  #repeat b times at d=0
                x2 = torch.cat([cls_token, x2], dim=1)

                x2 = x2 + self.pos_embedding[:, : T + 1]


                # Apply Transforrmer
                x2 = self.dropout(x2)
                x2 = x2.transpose(0, 1)   #transpose 0th with 1st dims

                x2 = self.transformer_dict["tf_"+str(0)](x2)
                x2 = x2[0]#cls

       
                predictions = torch.empty((10,0)).to(self.device)
        #                 pred_organ_lvl = torch.empty((0,1014))
                for idx, (name,_) in enumerate(FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS.items()):
                        #if torch.count_nonzero( org_list_dict["o_"+str(name)]
                        #if torch.count_nonzero( org_list_dict["o_"+str(name)])>0:
                         pred1 =  org_list_dict["o_"+str(name)]
                         print(f"predictions size is :{pred1.size()}")
                         predictions = torch.cat([predictions, self.mlp_head_dict["o_"+name](pred1) ],1)


                x = torch.cat([predictions , self.mlp_head_dict["o_8"](x2)],1)
                x = self.classify_head(x)


                return x

            def organ_selector(self, x, organs=False):
                if organs== True:
                    detected = face_shape_extractor(x , isPath=False)     #extract valid organs at dictionary detected
      
                    x = detected
                else:
                    #Loading the file
                    img2 = x.cpu().numpy().transpose(1, 2, 0)
                    #Format for the Mul:0 Tensor
                    img2= cv2.resize(img2,dsize=(260,260), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                    #Numpy array
                    np_image_data = np.asarray(img2)
                    #maybe insert float convertion here - see edit remark!
                    np_final = np.expand_dims(np_image_data,axis=0)

                    x=torch.from_numpy(np_final)
        #             x1 = x.squeeze(0).permute(1,2,0)
        #             cv2.resize(x1 , (3,260,260)) #resize for particular edge
        #             x = x1
                return x
```

And for training I use the following logic:

```py
        #CLEAR CUDA
        import gc
        gc.collect()
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()


        def train(model, loss_func, device, train_loader, optimizer,scheduler, epoch):
            #set model to training mode
            model.train()
            torch.set_grad_enabled(True)
            running_loss = []

            for batch_idx, (data, labels , paths) in enumerate(train_loader):

                data, labels = data.to(device), labels.squeeze(0).float().to(device)
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                output = model((data,paths))

                #check for any Nan Paramter
                is_nan = torch.stack([torch.isnan(p).any() for p in model.parameters()]).any()
                #print(f"nans detected ; {is_nan}")

                labels_copy =labels.clone()
                labels_inv = labels.cpu().apply_(lambda x: abs(x - 1))
                labels = torch.cat([labels_copy , labels_inv.to(device)] , 1)

                #labels = labels.repeat(2,1)
                #print(torch.isnan(output).any())
                #print(f"output is {output},size {output.size()} labels are {labels} , w size {labels.size()}")
                #loss=0
                #for j in range(8):
                    #loss_og = loss_func(output[BATCH_SIZE*j : BATCH_SIZE*(j+1) , :] , labels)
                    #print(f"Loss for organ {j} is: {loss_og.item()}")
                    #loss+=loss_og
               # print(f"The batch total loss is : {loss.item()}")
                loss = loss_func(output,labels)
                print(f"The batch total loss is: {loss}")
               # for name, p in model.named_parameters():
               #     if p.grad is not None:
               #         print(f"Printing parameter {p},name {name} data {p.grad.data}")
        #      #           print(p.grad.data)
               #     if p is None:
               #         print(f"Printing  None parameter {p}")

                loss.backward()

                #print("backward pass check")

                #exploding grads normalize
                torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 5 , error_if_nonfinite=True)
                optimizer.step()
                #LOG BATCH LOSS
                # wandb.log({'batch loss' : loss})
                running_loss.append(loss.detach().cpu().numpy())
                #         if batch_idx % 5 == 0:
            # #             wandb.log({'train-step-loss': np.mean(running_loss[-10:])})
            # #             pbar.set_postfix(loss='{:.3f} ({:.3f})'.format(running_loss[-1], np.mean(running_loss)))
                #             print("Epoch {} Iteration {}: Loss = {}, Number of mined triplets = {}".format(epoch, batch_idx, loss)
                #             )
                #LOG AVG EPOCH LOSS
                # wandb.log({'train-step-loss': np.mean(running_loss [-10:])})

                train_loss = np.mean(running_loss)
                #step scheduler
                scheduler.step()

            #print(f"Epoch loss is {np.mean(running_loss)}")
                #log epoch loss
        #         wandb.log({'train-epoch-loss': train_loss})
            pass

        # define validation logic
        @torch.no_grad()
        def validate_epoch(model, device, val_dataloader, criterion):
            model.eval()

            running_loss, y_true, y_pred = [], [], []
            for _,(x, y ,p) in enumerate(val_dataloader):
                x = x.to(device)
                y = y.to(device)

                outputs = model((x,p))
                labels_c =labels.copy()
                labels_inv = labels_c.cpu().apply_(lambda x: abs(x-1))
                labels = torch.cat([labels , labels_inv.to(device)] , 1)
                loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

                # loss calculation over batch
                running_loss.append(loss.cpu().numpy())

                # accuracy calculation over batch

                y_true.append(y.cpu())
                y_pred.append(outputs.cpu())

            y_true = torch.cat(y_true, 0).numpy()
            y_pred = torch.cat(y_pred, 0).numpy()

            #acc2 = accuracy()
            val_loss = np.mean(running_loss)
            acc = 100. * np.mean(y_true == y_pred)
            print(f"Validation loss is {val_loss} , accuracy {acc}")
            return {'val_loss': val_loss}



        device = torch.device("cuda")

        model = VisionTransformer(embed_dim=args.dk ,
                                hidden_dim = 750,
                                num_channels= 3,
                                num_heads=12,
                                num_layers=6,
                                num_classes = 1,
                                patch_size = 13,
                                num_patches = 64,
                                batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                device=device,dropout=0.2 ).to(device)

        #freeze pretrained vit w
       # for _ , vit in model.transformer_dict.items():
       #     for param in vit.encoder.parameters():
       #         param.requires_grad = False

        #init params xavier p
        #linear_cls = model.mlp_head[1]
        #torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform(linear_cls.weight)

        #register fwd hook for nan checking in forward pass
        activation = {}
        def get_activation(name):
            def hook(model, input, output):
                activation[name] = output.detach()
            return hook


        # model.fc2.register_forward_hook(get_activation('fc2'))
        # #get rdn dataloader sample
        # output = model(x)
        # print(activation['fc2'])

        lr =  0.1

        optimizer = optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=lr , weight_decay =0.1)

        d_model = 1000
        model_opt = NoamOpt(d_model, 1, 400,
                torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0, betas=(0.9, 0.98), eps=1e-9))


        scheduler1 = optim.lr_scheduler.ExponentialLR(optimizer, gamma=0.9)

        #scheduler1 = optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer)
        # scheduler1=lr_scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(optimizer, milestones=[1600, 150], gamma=0.1)
        num_epochs = 100

        loss_func = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy
        criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        criterion2 = torch.nn.BCELoss()
        criterion=criterion
        torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)

        # wandb.init()
        # wandb.log(hypers_dict)
        for epoch in range(1, num_epochs + 1):
            print(f"Current Epoch is: {epoch}")
            train(model, criterion, device, train_ds, optimizer,scheduler1, epoch)
            scheduler1.step()
            metrics = validate_epoch(model, device, val_ds, criterion)
            # wandb.log(metrics)
            print("The val.loss is:{}".format(metrics["val_loss"]))
```

Comment: You have to realize that public does not have enough computation power nor data to train a Vision Transformer model. Only big guys like G or MS or META can do it. We are not able to train such model with 20M image data. you have only 40k. To be able to train ViT, and have better results than CNN, you need to have >100M images and also spend at least 2000 GPU/days training based on papers to at least achieve better than CNN performance.